# How to match datatable rows to an array and display results in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable, match

I am using datatables and wish to show, upon page load, the previous selections that a user selected prior to page load. For example, if a user had selected and saved locations 3 and 4 then I want the datatables rows for 3 and 4 store ids to be highlighted, indicating that they are selected.

At present I have the following code to match up with and add the "selected" class to the rows that may be of match:

```
# Update the table to show those previously selected from the db
# Iterate through the previosuly selected ids, search on the id column 
# and set class to selected
for aLocation in previouslySelectedLocations
  indexes = root.table.rows().eq(0).filter((rowIdx) ->
    (if root.table.cell(rowIdx, 0).data() is aLocation.toString() then true else false)
  )
  root.table.rows(indexes).nodes().to$().addClass("selected")
```

But upon page load, nothing in the table is highlighted:

[image]

as it should be:

[image]

How can I get the "selected" class added properly to the rows that match the prevouslySelectedLocations array?

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it using javascript...call javascript function from server side.it may help.As you already know that pageload occurs when all the DOM element is loaded so that's the reason it is not appearing.So try to use javascript.

Comment: It's is in Ruby on rails do you have an example or some sort of other supports aside from the statement?